# Is implementing the RawComparator really that much faster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is implementing the RawComparator that much faster than extending WritableComparator? Looking at Text/LongWritable/etc, and their built-in comparators, it seems that they basically just read in the fields directly from the full byte array, instead of having a DataInput be used, and filling in the values into the key class.

In my case, I've got a custom key class, with multiple fields, of mixed types including some Strings. Trying to do it up with RawComparator sorta scares me, since it looks, at least on the surface, as possibly difficult to implement correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your right that raw comparators are definetly good when you're 100% sure the byte-to-byte comparisons reflect the data equivalence.

You could use a library such as apache's Thrift or avro to handle the binary serialization for you --- in this case, you won't have to worry about your raw data being inconsistently encoded in binary .

Binary comparisons are always faster than object de serialization... But "that much" master? Well that depends on how you define "that much" :)